# Average finder always prints “0”

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a program which finds the average of a set of data which someone enters. I have tried using this code:

```
var data = [];
var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
while (yesno) {
  var newdata = prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a number)");
  data.push(newdata);
  var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
}
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
if (!yesno) {
  while (i < data.length) {
    total + data[i];
    i++;
  }
  var average = total / data.length;
  document.write(average);
}
```

However, when I run it, no matter what I put in, it always prints “0”. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `total + data[i];` is an orphaned expression. You must use the `=` operator to assign to a variable for assignment to happen

Comment: I think you need to add the average variable and the document.write to your last while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
total + data[i];
```

This code will be executed at some result will be generated. But then nothing happens to that value. In javascript Numbers are primitive types. Except objects all data types object. You can't mutate them with `=`(assigning them to a value).

You need to use assignment expression.

```
total = total + data[i];
```

Or the short for that will be

```
total += data[i];
```

Another problem is that you are not converting the result of `prompt()` to a `Number`. Use Unary Plus `+` to convert string to number.

Below is corrected version of your code.

```js
var data = [];
var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
while (yesno) {
  var newdata = +prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a number)");
  data.push(newdata);
  var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
}
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
if (!yesno) {
  while (i < data.length) {
    total += data[i];
    i++;
  }
  var average = total / data.length;
  document.write(average);
}
```

A cleaner and better version can be achieved using `do-while` and `reduce()`

```js
var data = [];
var yesno;
do{
  var newdata = +prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a number)");
  yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
  data.push(newdata);
}
while (yesno);
var total = data.reduce((ac,a) => ac + a,0);
var average = total / data.length;
document.write(average);
```

Answer (score 3):

`total + data[i]` is an "orphaned expression". Use `=` or `+=`.

```js
var data = [];
var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
while (yesno) {
  var newdata = +prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a number)");
  data.push(newdata);
  var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
}
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
if (!yesno) {
  while (i < data.length) {
    total += data[i];
    i++;
  }
  var average = total / data.length;
  document.write(average);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var data = [];
var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more data?");
while (yesno) {
    var newdata = prompt("Enter a piece of data (must be a 
    number)");
    data.push(newdata);
    var yesno = confirm("Would you like to add more 
    data?");
}
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
if (!yesno) {
    while (i < data.length) {
        total += data[i];
        i ++;
        var average = total / data.length;
document.write(average);
        } 
    }
```